# How do I send 10,000 ~ 20,000 bytes data over TCP?

Tags: c++, tcp

Can I send about 10,000 ~ 20,000 bytes data over TCP? I am transferring an image (60 by 60) from Android client to linux server. On android it seems ok. On server side, if I try to send the picture data back to client, then it doesn't work. On client side, if I parse then I got some weird number that I shouldn't get.

Is there any technical problem of transferring a big data over TCP? How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance..

```
char* PictureResponsePacket::toByte(){

    /*
     * HEADER
     *
     * Magic number (4)
     * Data length  (4)
     * Packet Id    (2)
     * Packet type  (2)
     * Device Id    (48)
     *
     */

    /*
     * BODY
     *
     * Nickname  (48)
     * deviceId  (4)
     * m_pictureSize
     */

    int offset = 0;

    int headerLength = sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(short) + sizeof(short) + 48;
    int bodyLength = 48 + 4 + m_pictureSize;
    int dataLength = headerLength + bodyLength;
    m_dataLength = dataLength;

    log("PictureResponsePacket::toByte(), data length %d \n", m_dataLength);

    char *sendBuffer = new char[dataLength];
    memset(sendBuffer, 0x00, dataLength);

    char *ptr = sendBuffer;

    /*
     * -------------
     * HEADER
     * -------------
     */
    /*
     * Magic number
     */
    memcpy(ptr + offset, m_magicNumberBuffer, sizeof(int));
    offset += sizeof(int);

    /*
     * Data length
     */


    memcpy(ptr + offset, &m_dataLength, sizeof(int));
    offset += sizeof(int);

    /*
     * Packet id
     */
    memcpy(ptr + offset, &m_packetId, sizeof(short));
    offset += sizeof(short);

    /*
     * Packet type
     */
    memcpy(ptr + offset, &m_packetType, sizeof(short));
    offset += sizeof(short);

    /*
     *Device Id
     */

    memcpy(ptr + offset, m_deviceId.c_str(), m_deviceId.size());
    offset += 48;

    /*
     * -------------
     * BODY
     * -------------
     */
    memcpy(ptr + offset, m_senderDeviceId.c_str(), m_senderDeviceId.size());
    offset += 48;

    memcpy(ptr + offset, &m_pictureSize, sizeof(int));
    offset += sizeof(int);

    memcpy(ptr + offset, m_pictureData, m_pictureSize);
    offset += m_pictureSize;


    return sendBuffer;


}
```

I am getting char* this way and sending it like this

```
                char * sBuffer = reponsePacket->toByte();
                int remainLength = reponsePacket->getDataLength();
                int currentSentLength = 0;
                SocketClient *client = work->getClient();

                while(remainLength > 0){

                    if(remainLength >= MAX_LENGTH)
                        currentSentLength = send(client->getFd(), sBuffer, MAX_LENGTH, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
                    else
                        currentSentLength = send(client->getFd(), sBuffer, remainLength, MSG_NOSIGNAL);

                    if(currentSentLength == -1){
                        log("WorkHandler::workLoop, connection has been lost \n");
                        break;
                    }

                    sBuffer += currentSentLength;
                    remainLength -= currentSentLength;
```

Comment: Yes, you can send that amount of data, but not in one packet normally.

Comment: Show some code, there could be many issues.

Comment: 20kB is Big Data? O RLY?

Comment: Until someone tells me I'm out of my mind, im still going to insist at least part of the problem is endianness. Check out http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Byte-Order.html and convert all your values to network byte order before sending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is easy (20K is not "big"). By far the most common reason something like this happens, is disregarding the return codes of `send` and `recv`. You should keep a few things in mind:

- `send(2)` can't always copy all the data from user space to kernel space. Check the returned value
- The data doesn't arrive all at the same time, so you will have to `recv` a few times before getting all of it

In practice, on many systems you might get away with `send`ing large amounts of data (the kernel will laugh at your 20K) but you will have to receive in a loop. Here is a function heavily inspired by Stevens readn. Use it instead of `recv`

```
ssize_t
readn(int fd, void *vptr, size_t n)
{
    size_t nleft;
    ssize_t nread;
    char *ptr;

    ptr = vptr;
    nleft = n;
    while (nleft > 0) {
        if ((nread = read(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                /* Loop back and call read again. */
                nread = 0;
            else
                /* Some other error; can't handle. */
                return -1;
        } else if (nread == 0)
            /* EOF. */
            break;

        nleft -= nread;
        ptr += nread;
    }
    return n - nleft;
}
```

#### EDIT

You seem to be forgetting about endianness (as Andrew Finnell suspected). For every integer, you should do something like this before sending (before `memcpy`):

```
m_dataLength = htonl(m_datalength);
```

And this when receiving:

```
m_dataLength = ntohl(m_datalength);
```

Comment: You still don't account for Endian problems. Java is always big-endian. native code on x86 understand little-endian.

Comment: I'm leaving my previous comment there, because technically it's true. But this code is just a network streamer. He would still need to use a decoder in which _that_ would fix the endian problems.

Comment: @Andrew Finnell I answered before the OP edited and added the code. Indedd it seems he isn't using htons / htonl like he should be.

Comment: And neither of us could of known until he posted the code. I had taken a guess to begin with until the code was updated. As yours is now the most complete +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying you can successfully send and read the image if you sent it from Android to your Linux machine? If not then it sounds like it could be an [Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue, if your Linux Server process was not written in Java.

**Update**

Since cnicutar has a great answer I'd like to offer an alternative to having to do your protocol manually.

[Google Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

When using it, it will automatically convert from host to network and back. It also can be used to create C++ and Java bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I think **strace** may help here both on client and server side. Look for network errors and the amount of sent/received data in strace log.